# How to send message as bot disconnects using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

My attempt:

```py
@bot.event
async def close():
    await bot.get_channel(619401742672395168).send("Bot Disconnected")
```

I want to be able to do a few actions as it is disconnected.

Comment: once it is disconnected, you won't be able to send messages to channels anymore

Comment: If you are referring when disconnected from a voice channel, it's possible, otherwise, it won't be possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`on_disconnect`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_disconnect) event, but read the scenarios in which it is triggered: you might not be able to connect to discord because you have been disconnected.

Comment: The only possible way I can think of is actually reconnect, send the message then disconnect again